# How can I turn off the setting where intellij automatically creates brackets?

Tags: reactjs, intellij-idea

[image]

When I type position, then equal, make brackets automatically generated.
I don't want it. Any turn off option or change?

Answer (score 0):

Please try setting **Add for JSX attributes:** to *None* (or *Quotes* if you prefer quotes instead of braces being added) in **Preferences | Editor | Code Style | HTML | Other**; you can also set it to *Based on type* to have either braces or quotes auto-completed depending on props type